# MS SQL Make a column of one table depend on other table values sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table "Order" like this, which contains information about the order.

`Order ID | ... | Order Total`

The order, however, consists of several items, there's also an "Item Order" table:

`Item Order ID | Order ID | Item ID`

And the "Item" table:

`Item ID | Cost`

Thus, Order <-> Item Order have a one-to-many relationship and Item Order <-> Item have many-to-one relationship.

Logically, the Order Total should depend on the cost of each item order in it, which would add the cost of the Item to the Total.

How do I set up the dependencies so, that the Order Total depends on all Item Orders corresponding to this order and sums up all needed Item costs? I guess it should also update upon adding new item orders to the order each time.

Comment: I'd recommend not *storing* data that you can *calculate*, unless and until you can demonstrate an actual performance issue with just calculating the result on the fly. As soon as you *store* redundant data, you open yourself to the opportunity that it's *wrong*.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, I'd normally prefer not to store redundant, potentially incorrect data. If, however, there's a performance issue with calculating the total on the fly, the next best option is to get the *system* to do the calculations for you. This is an option if you use an *indexed view*.

Table setup:

```
create table dbo.Orders (
    OrderID int not null,
    /* NO Total here */
    constraint PK_Orders PRIMARY KEY (OrderID)
)
go
create table dbo.Items (
    ItemID int not null,
    Cost decimal (19,4) not null,
    constraint PK_Items PRIMARY KEY (ItemID)
)
go
create table dbo.OrderItems (
    OrderItemID int not null,
    OrderID int not null,
    ItemID int not null,
    /* I'd normally prefer Order/Item/Quantity and making Order/Item the PK */
    constraint PK_OrderItems PRIMARY KEY (OrderItemID),
    constraint FK_OrderItems_Orders FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) references Orders (OrderID),
    constraint FK_OrderItems_Items FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) references Items (ItemID)
)
```

And now we can create the view:

```
create view dbo.OrderTotals
with schemabinding
as
    select
        OrderID,
        COUNT_BIG(*) as LineCount, /* Required for indexed view with aggregate */
        SUM(Cost) as OrderTotal
    from
        dbo.Items i
            inner join
        dbo.OrderItems o
            on
                i.ItemID = o.ItemID
    group by
        OrderID
go
create unique clustered index IX_OrderTotals on OrderTotals (OrderID)
```

Now, as you perform inserts, updates and deletes against the OrderItems or Items tables, this view's index (which actually contains all of the view data) is automatically updated for you.

This avoids any concerns about corner cases which you may miss if you use e.g. triggers to perform the updates manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two triggers on `Item Order` and `Item` tables.

**Trigger on `Item` table:**

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER T_Item_Recalc_Order_Total
ON Item
FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE o
        SET [Order Total] = c.[Cost]
    FROM Order o
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT   i_o.[Order_ID]
                    ,SUM(Cost) AS Cost
            FROM Item_Order i_o
                INNER JOIN Item i
                    ON i.[Item ID] = i_o.[Item ID]
            WHERE i_o.[Item ID] IN (
                -- Sum up cost for changed rows only
                SELECT COALESCE(d.[Item ID], i.[Item ID]) AS [Item ID]
                FROM deleted d
                    FULL OUTER JOIN inserted i
                        ON d.[Item ID] = i.[Item ID]
                WHERE d.[Item ID] IS NULL OR i.[Item ID] IS NULL OR d.[Cost] <> i.[Cost]
            )
            GROUP BY i_o.[Order_ID]
        ) c
            ON o.[Order_ID] = c.[Order_ID]

END
```

**Trigger on `Item Order` table:**

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER T_Item_Order_Recalc_Order_Total
ON Item_Order
FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE o
        SET [Order Total] = c.[Cost]
    FROM Order o
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT   i_o.[Order_ID]
                    ,SUM(Cost) AS Cost
            FROM Item_Order i_o
                INNER JOIN Item i
                    ON i.[Item ID] = i_o.[Item ID]
            WHERE i_o.[Order_ID] IN (
                -- Sum up cost for changed rows only
                SELECT deleted.[Order_ID]
                UNION
                SELECT inserted.[Order_ID]
            )
            GROUP BY i_o.[Order_ID]
        ) c
            ON o.[Order_ID] = c.[Order_ID]

END
```

Comment: The first trigger is broken. The `IF` assumes that `inserted` and `deleted` contain either zero or one row. That's an unsafe assumption.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks. I moved that logic into the `WHERE` clause